# How to set background image?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, imageicon

I created a jframe with jmenubar and added a background image.Then I added a sub menu.But the background image disappeared.How can I solve this problem?See the code below.

```
    public Welcome() {
    //JFrame frame=new JFrame();
    setTitle("PAIN AND PALIATIVE CARE UNIT VAZHAYOOR");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);


    JLabel background=new JLabel(new ImageIcon("src/startApplication/Helping-Hands_1.png")); 
    background.setBackground(Color.white);
    add(background);


    mbar=new JMenuBar();
    menu = new JMenu("Medicine");
    menu.add(makeMenuItem("Add Stock"));
    menu.add(makeMenuItem("Add Medicine Details"));
    menu.add(makeMenuItem("Spent Medicine"));
    menu.add(makeMenuItem("Check Availability"));
    menu.add(makeMenuItem("View Stock Details"));

    viewMenu=new JMenu("Daily");

    viewMenu=new JMenu("Report");
    viewMenu.add(makeMenuItem("Daily"));
    viewMenu.add(makeMenuItem("Monthly"));
    viewMenu.add(makeMenuItem("Periodical"));

    funds = new JMenu("Funds");
    funds.add(makeMenuItem("Add"));
    funds.add(makeMenuItem("Edit"));
    funds.add(makeMenuItem("View"));
    funds.add(makeMenuItem("Mark Expense"));
    funds.add(add(viewMenu));



    mbar.add(menu);
    mbar.add(funds);
    setJMenuBar(mbar);
    setSize(getMaximumSize());
    setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling `JFrame#add` twice, thereby displacing the `JLabel` component at the `BorderLayout.CENTER` location of the `JFrame`

```
funds.add(add(viewMenu));
          ^^^
```

replace with

```
funds.add(viewMenu);
```